# first element is not pushing inside empty array in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, push

trying to push data coming to "id" to "selectedUserId" array, but first element is not inserting.
selectedUserId array does not contain first pushed element, push is only working from second element onwards.

```
   const handleSelectOne=(e)=>{
   const id = e.target.value;
 
   console.log(id,"handling")
   
   if(!selectedUserIds.includes(id))
   {
     selectedUserIds.push(id)
   }
   else 
   {
     selectedUserIds.pop(id)
   }
   
   setCheckedStatusOne(!checkedStatusOne[id])

   }


const handleDeleteSelectedClick=() =>{
   
let deletionItemsNo = selectedUserIds.length

selectedUserIds.map((id)=>{
 
  return console.log(id, "<== element inside selecteduserids array")
})
console.log(deletionItemsNo, "<== number of elements in array")
}
```

**output**
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnGSd.png)

Comment: have you initialised your array? let selectedUserIds = [];

Comment: yes, initialised the array.
const selectedUserIds=[];

Comment: Can you add a `console.log('pushing', id)` and `console.log('popping')` before actual push and pop? Then you will see when it pushes and what. I suspect it's not pushing anything.

Comment: @sergiyostrovsky if(!selectedUserIds.includes(id)) { console.log("pushing",id) selectedUserIds.push(id) } else { console.log("popping",id) selectedUserIds.pop(id) } **output** 1 handling | pushing 1 | 2 handling | pushing 2 | 3 handling | pushing 3 | 2 <== element inside selecteduserids array | 3 <== element inside selecteduserids array | 2 <== number of elements in array'

Comment: Ok, thanks, it's hard to say what is the reason, but it's certainly not JS misbehaviour. Maybe you modify this array in other places? You could try removing all pops and other modifications of this array and see how it works with only this push.

Answer (score 0):

`.pop()` method doesn't accept any arguments. It used for removing the last array item.

To be able to insert element in the beginning you should use `.unshift(id)`

Comment: I don't want to insert the element to first place of array. I just want my first element which I push to array to be there in array.
Basically, its ignoring the first element, from second element onwards its working fine.

Comment: could you please share the whole component code?

Comment: whole code will be too big, I'm adding where the handleSelectOne function is invoked.

<td><input type="checkbox" className="checkBox" checked={checkedStatusOne[obj.id]} value={obj.id} onChange={(e) => {handleSelectOne(e)}} name="selectOne"/></td>